# How can I substitute my FILTER() formula for prior versions of Excel?

Tags: excel, indexing, filter, match, aggregate

I created this `FILTER()` formula which works perfectly, however, turns out I need a formula that accomplishes the same thing, but in Excel versions prior to 365.

```
=FILTER('Employees List'!A2:A42,('Employees List'!B2:B42<>"Off Shift")*('Employees List'!C2:C42<>"No"),"No Employees On Shift")
```

Basically, what the formula does is: If column B does not equal `Off Shift`,  and Column C does not contain "No", then return the value in column A.

I did not know how to do this any other way, which is why I created the FILTER() formula.  I have currently 42 names in column A, and I didn't know how to return these values while also not pulling duplicates

Would greatly appreciate any help.  Please let me know if I need to provide further clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found one way to do this. 
Column A: List of Employee Names 
Column B: Identifies whether Employee is 'On Shift' or 'Off Shift' 
Column C: Identifies whether Employee is otherwise Available via 'Yes' or 'No' 
I'm using column L as a `Helper` column to answer the criteria portion, using the below formula:

```
=IF(AND(B2<>"Off Shift",C2<>"No"),"1","0")
```

Then I'm using the below `Array` to substitute the `FILTER()` formula, which I drag down to the extent of the data in column A.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$42,MATCH(0,IF("1"=$L$2:$L$42,COUNTIF($O$1:$O1,$A$2:$A$42),""),0)),"")
```

I thought this would have had to be an `Array`, but it seems to be working without the `Array` being activated.

Was hoping there would be a cleaner solution, so would love if anyone has feedback.